# Винительный падеж иногда прямой? Когда - иногда?

Tags: падежи

Википедия извещает:

> Выделяют прямой падеж (именительный и иногда также винительный) и
>   косвенные падежи (остальные)...

Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры прямого винительного падежа.

Comment: Не надо так буквально понимать Википедию. Она права в том, что кто-то *иногда* называет. Вот V.V.  назвал потому, что опирался на иное (чем у Розенталя) системное определение. Это не значит, что с таким подходом все согласятся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Википедия извещает:
>
> *Выделяют прямой падеж (именительный и иногда также винительный) и косвенные падежи (остальные)...*

Лучше, на мой взгляд, ориентироваться не на Википедию, а на печатные книги. А в них так:

> ***прямой падеж***
>
> ***То же, что именительный падеж***. ср.: косвенный падеж.
>
> *Словарь-справочник лингвистических терминов. Изд. 2-е. — М.: Просвещение. Розенталь Д. Э., Теленкова М. А.. 1976.*

.

> ***косвенный падеж***
>
> ***Любой падеж, кроме именительного.*** Объединение родительного, дательного, винительного, творительного и предложного падежей в одну
>   категорию косвенного падежа основано на том, что все они выражают
>   синтаксическую зависимость от других слов в словосочетании или
>   предложении, **в противоположность прямому (именительному) падежу**,
>   занимающему независимое синтаксическое положение по отношению к другим
>   словам.
>
> *Словарь-справочник лингвистических терминов. Изд. 2-е. — М.: Просвещение. Розенталь Д. Э., Теленкова М. А.. 1976.*

Answer (score 0):

Вот единственный доступный мне автор, дающий сколь-нибудь осмысленное определение "прямого винительного" - как синоним т. н. "винительного объекта". 
Название "прямой винительный" порождено, видимо, представлением о т.н. "прямом дополнении" - дополнении при переходном глаголе: в сочетании, позволяющем образовать страдательное причастие.

Здесь есть над чем подумать, Пешковский - автор интересный, не знаю, правда, авторское ли это название, или в *"Изложении..."* появилось. Одно ясно: в Вики вряд ли этот имелось в виду; и название совсем не общепринятое, и формулировка не та: не "*иногда* также винительный", а "некоторые случаи винительного"

> 1. Винительный внешнего объекта: крепить смычку, тащить салазки, читать книгу, любить отца, утолять жажду и т.д. и внутреннего объекта,
>      т.е. такого, который возникает только в результате данного действия:
>      печь пироги, строить дом, петь песни и т.д. Этот винительный выражает
>      предмет, на который непосредственно переходит действие, выраженное в
>      глаголе (отсюда и глаголы, управляющие этим винительным, называются
>      «переходными» или «собственно-переходными»). Как видно из примеров,
>      здесь имеется в виду не только физическое воздействие на предмет (беру
>      книгу), но и образный переход действия на предмет (люблю отца, знаю
>      арифметику, утоляю жажду), причем и сам этот предмет часто бывает
>      образным (арифметика, жажда). Винительный объекта является падежом,
>      наиболее «сильно» управляемым (***другие названия для него: прямой
>      винительный***, прямой объект, прямое дополнение). Глаголы, управляющие
>      им, всегда допускают страдательный оборот: книга берется, дом
>      строится, отец любим и т.д.

*(выделено мной - b-s)*

Р.Н. ГРАЦИАНСКАЯ
"Синтаксическая система А.М. Пешковского в кратком изложении"

http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200800104

***Другими словами, по данному определению "прямой винительный" - это винительный прямого дополнения***.